# Delete rows when no data is present in column 28 using bash (awk/sed)

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, sed

Below is a brief example of what my .csv files look like:

```
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","","N"
```

In the third column (the "Z" column), I have cells that are missing (rows 3,6, and 9). Using awk or sed preferably, I would like to specifically target column 3, and if any of the cells are blank, I would like to remove the entire line. My end result would be:

```
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
```

For my actual project, below is an exact copy of one of my files -
https://github.com/drphillgood/riotapidata/blob/master/csv/game3.csv. You will see in column 28 (participants__participantId) only certain cells have data (same for the last column, participants__playerName). If one of the cells in this column is blank, I want to delete the entire row using a .sh script. The end file would like like this - https://github.com/drphillgood/riotapidata/blob/master/csv/game3_v2.csv

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've provided the raw sample file as well as a view of what it looks like in excel through Github

sample view https://github.com/drphillgood/riotapidata/blob/master/csv/game3.csv

raw code https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drphillgood/riotapidata/master/csv/game3.csv

I would like for the end product to look like this:

https://github.com/drphillgood/riotapidata/blob/master/csv/game3_v2.csv

Comment: No links. Thanks you.

Comment: `"X","Y","Z"
"X","Y","Z"
"X","Y",""
"X","Y","Z"
"X","Y","Z"
"X","Y",""
"X","Y","Z"
"X","Y","Z"
"X","Y",""` 

Here is a very simplistic example. I want to select column 3 (the Z column) and delete any rows that are blank (rows 3, 6, 9 in this example)

Comment: @Cyrus I have updated my original question. Hopefully this will be more accurate and minimal on what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do any of your fields contain commas within them?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson they do not contain any commas within the fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simpler AWK command:

```
awk -F , '$3 != "\"\"" {print}' inputfile > outputfile
```

Set the field separator to a comma and print every line that has the third field consisting only of `""`.

This is not robust enough to handle CSV files that contain commas within the fields. It expects the empty field to consist of empty quotes.

Comment: This works for the small example I created, but when applied to the actual documents I will be using (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drphillgood/riotapidata/master/csv/game3.csv) this did not work.

Comment: @USTropics: Did you change the 3 to a 28? I'm not going to try to read your data file or copy it and run it. You will need to do some troubleshooting. Sources of problems could be unicode quotes instead of ASCII quotes, some unseen characters within your empty field in addition to the quotes, etc.

Comment: @USTropics Might be a line ending problem in the big csv? windows vs unix linendings? What OS produced the vsc and on what OS do you execute the awk command? I tried my original awk with the csv from github, copy pasted from the browser into an editor on Linux, saved the pasted content and the awk did work.

Comment: @LarsFischer: Thanks for filling out my "etc."! That's definitely a possibility.

Comment: @EdMorton

You should extend someone more than an hour to respond, especially when it was evident I needed to look at the file and how it was being converted instead of all solutions that were clearly working on my example. Patience, my friend.

I have discovered the issue as several posters alluded to above; simply put, downloading the files from github were causing the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` script that do the trick.

```
awk -F '","' '!$3{next}1' input.csv
```

output:

```
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
```

explanation:

```
BEGIN {FS = "\",\""}  # input line field separator ","
!$3{next}             # if empty string in 3rd input field, skip
1                     # print current line
```

#### Update:

Following comments bellow and provided test CSV file in the link.

Testing for field $28

Output for `awk -F '","' '!$28{next}1' input.txt  | awk -F '","' '{print $28}'`

```
participants__participantId
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: This also works for the small example I created, but when applied to a larger file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drphillgood/riotapidata/master/csv/game3.csv) this did not work. I'm attempting to delete all rows where column 28 is empty (participants__participantId)

Comment: @USTropics  the test script `awk -F '","' '!$28{next}1' input.txt  | awk -F '","' '{print $28}'` prints the  value of field 28. It provides `participants__participantId` and number `1 ..  10`. I run it on the csv file your provided.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! These solutions also worked. I discovered the formatting from Github was the reason for the failed conversions. Converting directly from json to csv on the CentOs server fixed this.

Comment: thank you glad it works for you. please express gratitude to all contributors with upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with sed command:
`sed -r -n '/^([^,]*,){27}""/! p' yourfile`

Use either 27 for your full file or 2 for your minimal example to specify the number of fields **before** the column you need to check.

The regexp prints (`p`, together with `-n` option) lines that does not (`/.../!` the exclamation negates) match the condition:

- `^` match from the line start,
- `([^,]*,)[27}` 27 fields separated by comma that might degenerate to just 27 commas,
- `""` only double quotes in the next field

Comment: Wanted to provide a quick update and also state this worked after fixing my file format issues and is a great solution for inline edits.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '$3 ~ /"Z"/{print $0}' file

"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
"X","Y","Z","N"
```